# Configuring Intellij formatter to wrap after method annotation?

Tags: intellij-idea

After importing a code style, my code does not wrap after method annotations. Could anyone point me to the settings which will force

`@Override
public void...`

Instead of

`@Override public void`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for "Method Annotations" towards the bottom of that very list.  Select "Wrap always" to ensure that they get their own line.  The preview on the right (at the bottom) will show you what that looks like.